# How to import many csv files to tables in MATLAB with names that correspond to their filenames

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a folder full of csv data files that I want to import to MATLAB. The import function will be the same for each of them. Their names follow a pattern, e.g. 'a0-b0.csv', 'a0-b5.csv', 'a0-b10.csv', 'a0-b15.csv' ... 'a2-b0' etc.

I want to import all these files at once. I want to import them as tables with sensible names that correspond to the data they contain.

Doing something like

```
filepath = 'file/path/'
for (a = [0, 2])
    for (b = [0:5:50])
        filename = strcat(filepath, 'a', num2str(a), '-b', num2str(b), '.csv')
        varname = strcat('a', num2str(a), '_b', num2str(b))
        varname = importfile(filename, startrow, endrow)
    end
end
```

made sense in concept to me.

As 'varname' itself is the variable, not the string it contains, this does not do what I want. I've seen a lot of answers to similar situations suggesting `eval()`, while simultaneously vehemently advocating against it.

`eval()` has side effects that make it annoying to implement. Everyone's intense aversion to it make me wonder if it's worth putting in the effort to try to implement it.

I can think of no other way to do this, however. I don't see how using arrays (the recommended alternative) would result in appropriate/relevant names.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to automatically import many csv files to tables in MATLAB with names that correspond to their filenames?

---

(Regarding duplicates: I haven't yet found a question that addresses the automatic creation of corresponding variable names, which is the main issue here)

Comment: use a `struct` to store the tables. do not use `eval`. ever. if you find yourself having to use it, time to rethink what you're doing.

Comment: More broadly, you want to use [dynamic field referencing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/)

Answer (score 0):

As @transversality condition wrote in their comment, you should rethink you approach.

I'd suggest two steps:

1. If you are about to change files in and import htem again, create `.mat` file with already imported data and check hwther to rescan the folder or load the `.mat` file.
2. Decide whether you want to use `struct` class or `cell` class to contain your data.

The code for `struct` can be:

```
filepath = 'file/path/';                    % define the data folder
FileNames=dir('filepath\*.csv');            % list all csv. files within filepath
N=numel(FileNames);                         % count the csv files
DATA(N)=struct('name','','data',[]);        % preallocate DATA 
for (ii=1:N)
    Temp=regexp(FileNames(ii).name,'\.','split');  % separate file name and abbreviation
    DATA(ii).name = Temp{1};                % save the file name
    DATA(ii).data = importfile([filepath,'\',FileNames(ii).name], startrow, endrow);   % save the data
end
```

The code for `cell` can be:

```
filepath = 'file/path/';                    % define the data folder
FileNames=dir('filepath\*.csv');            % list all csv. files within filepath
N=numel(FileNames);                         % count the csv files
DATA=cell(2,N);                             % preallocate DATA
for (ii=1:N)
    Temp=regexp(FileNames(ii).name,'\.','split');  % separate file name and abbreviation
    DATA{1,ii} = Temp{1};                % save the file name
    DATA{2,ii} = importfile([filepath,'\',FileNames(ii).name], startrow, endrow);   % save the data
end
```

In both cases you have to find the appropriate line by, for example, `DATA(find(strcmpi(DATA.name,'<name>))).data`.

You can also use the `cell` approach to create `struct`. Suppose we've run the code for `cell`.

Then command

```
DataStruct=struct(DATA{:});
```

will allow you to access your data via `Data.Struct.<filename>` command directly.